# Firefox forces to install updates on older version

Tags: firefox, updates, auto-updates

I have decided to use an older version (78.0) of Firefox ESR for testing but whenever I try to install the Firefox, it quickly starts to auto-update before I disable it. I rebooted Firefox and I got version 115.0.

I just want to stay in older version of Firefox but I'm too late to disable updates. I have also checked 'Check for updates but let you choose' in Preferences but while Firefox already installed the newer version.

I'm using Debian 11 bookworm.

Comment: Can you disconnect the computer from the Internet, install Firefox, configure it, then re-connect to the Internet?

Comment: Oh I disconnected computer from Internet and I can now use Firefox 78 without allowing updates. That is an easy solution. Thanks. :D